# Adding/editing JS inside iFrame with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, greasemonkey

I am trying to target an iFrame inside a page with GreaseMonkey, but I am having some issues finding a correct solution. Within this iFrame, a file called common.js is loaded within its head, which I am trying to overwrite with another js file. Overwriting an external script works in the main page, but not within the frame. Can anyone point me in the right direction? jQuery or JS can be used, it matters not.

Comment: is the script being injected at all?